# In FTP Is it possible to move files from one location to other location

Tags: unix, ftp

I am creating one process that will fetch the flat files from FTP and files will be load into a database. yes i am able to copy required file from FTP to Unix but not able to move files in FTP server.

Kindly Assist.

Thanks!!

Comment: There is no such operation in FTP protocol.
Other sources in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123229/copying-files-on-a-remote-server-over-ftp

Answer (score 2):

You can use the FTP `rename` command with full paths to move files. E.g.

```
rename /old/path/yourfile.txt /new/path/yourfile.txt
```

See: http://www.webcom.com/help/ftp/rename.shtml